# Какими методами можно определить использует ли юзер прокси или нет?

Tags: прокси, proxy

Какими методами можно определить использует ли юзер прокси или нет? Жду все возможные варианты и идеи. :)

Comment: а какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к программированию?

Comment: Непосредственно прямое. Вопрос идет о юзере, т.е пользователе, пользователе чего, наверное какого того ПО, значит зачем то нужно определить не скрывается ли юзер за прокси. Доступно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это HTTP-заголовки
"Via"
"X-Forwarded-For"
"Client-ip"
"Forwarded"

Comment: Вообщем то, вопрос, отпал уже давно, но задача был определить проксю не через веб-сервер.